# solving $\int \cos^2(2x)\sin(2x)\,dx$

Tags: integration

> $$\int \cos^2(2x)\sin(2x)\,dx$$

I have tried $\int \cos^2(2x)\sin(2x)\,dx=\int (1-\sin^2(2x))\sin(2x)\,dx$

And $\int \cos^2(2x)\sin(2x)\,dx=\int (\cos^2(2x))2\cos x\sin x\, dx$

But no substitution seems to work.

Comment: Have you tried differentiating $\cos^3 2x?$

Comment: How about $u = \cos 2x$?

Answer (score 2):

$u = \cos{2x} \Rightarrow \frac{du}{dx} = -2\sin{(2x)}$ so $\cos^2{(2x)} \sin{(2x)} dx = -\frac{u^2}{2} du$

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Not sure, your post seems fine. Perhaps not as detailed as others, but fine nonetheless

Answer (score 2):

$$\int  \cos ^{ 2 } (2x)sin(2x)dx=-\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \int { \cos ^{ 2 }{ \left( 2x \right) d\left( \cos { \left( 2x \right)  }  \right)  }  } =-\frac { \cos ^{ 3 }{ \left( 2x \right)  }  }{ 6 } +C$$
substitution here is $u=\cos { \left( 2x \right)  } $

Answer (score 1):

$$u=\cos (2x)$$
$$du = -2\sin (2x)dx$$

so with the substitution we have $$\frac{-1}{2}\int u^2 du $$
from here I think you can do the work yourself.